# Initialize a New iOS CloudKit Int64 Field When Added to an Existing Record Type Swift 3.x

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am creating version 1.x of my iOS mobile application using cloudKit.  I need to add 1 attribute to an existing record from version 1.0 that is an int64.  Is there a way to get the value for this field to default to 0 or 1 for all records that already exist in the database for this record type without writing a script that is embedded and runs in the app at start-up of the download?  This record exists in the customer's private database cloud instance.

If there isn't a way out of the box with cloudKit, can someone share iOS swift 3.x code that would update all records for the 1 attribute when the app starts up once after download?

Comment: I am running into this issue as well - did you end up solving this?

Comment: I didn't find a way to default the value on column creation.  I coded around when I fetched the record with: `if let wantFigureCount = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kWantFigureCount) as? Int64 {
                                    self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantFigureCount = wantFigureCount
                                }
                                else {  // if the value from CloudKit is blank, set it to a default value...`